# Lasagne not importing using Python3 in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, python

I am trying to use the lasagne module in Python3, but any time it hits the import statement, in the code I'm running, I get a "not found" error. I had a similar issue with theano because it was only referencing Python 2.7 and not 3, but I managed to resolve that by re-installing the developer version. I tried that method with lasagne, but without success. It also seems like uninstalling 2.7 is not an option because of the long list of system software that is dependent on it when I mark it for uninstallation.

I installed lasagne and theano with pip. I used this syntax: 'python3 -m pip install lasagne --user'. The contents of 2.7 has lasagne and theano, but 3.5 only has easy_install.py.

The following snippet used to halt at the import theano statement, but since reinstalling theano it now halts at the import lasagne statement.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor.nnet.neighbours

# Support ansi colors in Windows too.
if sys.platform == 'win32':
import colorama

# Deep Learning Framework
import lasagne
from lasagne.layers import Conv2DLayer as ConvLayer, Pool2DLayer as PoolLayer
from lasagne.layers import InputLayer, ConcatLayer
```

This is the error I get when running the example statement provided with the software:

```
$ python3 doodle.py --style samples/Gogh.jpg --content samples/Seth.png  --output SethAsGogh.png --device=cpu -phases=4 --iterations=40
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doodle.py", line 94, in <module>
    import lasagne
ImportError: No module named 'lasagne'
```

The way I see it, they should both throw an error given that 3.5 doesn't contain either. I'm also not understanding why it is only installing to 2.7.

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I'm not an expert so I am likely searching forums incorrectly and not recognizing related solutions to this problem.

Update: I had installed Anaconda some time ago and I was unaware that it changes the path in .bashrc. Luckily, it makes a backup of the original .bashsrc file so I switched to the backup and now modules are importing just fine.

Comment: What did you actually install (python? lasagne? theano?)?  And how (apt-get? pip?)?  What is the content of `site-packages` for both pythons?

Comment: I installed lasagne and theano with pip. I used this syntax: 'python3 -m pip install lasagne --user'. The contents of 2.7 is empty, but 3.5 has lasagne, Lasgane-0.1-3.5.egg-info, pkg_resources, _pycache_, setuptools, setuptools-27.1.2.dist-info, theano, Theano-0.8.2-py3.5.egg-info, and easy_install.py.

Comment: Good, now please [edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/309066/edit) and add that information in there.  Other pieces of useful information that are needed are: the code you're trying to execute (minimal example) and the error printed to the console (there is more than one type of import errors in python)

Comment: Edited the post. Thanks for the help with clarifying the problem.

Comment: Ok, you are using `-m pip install lasagne --user` this should install things inside `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`.  What are the contents of that directory?

Comment: Ah, ok. I updated the question. I'm more confused now since niether theano or lasagne are in 3.5, but only lasagne is throwing an import error.

Comment: `theano` must be somewhere inside `sys.path`.  If you check all directories in there you shall find it (and that will give a good clue on what pip actually did).  One way to do it is `echo 'import sys;print("\n".join(sys.path))'|python3|while read x; do ls -d1 $x/*; done`.  (Btw, to test I have installed lasagne on my Arch using `pip --user` but I cannot replicate your error)